How to capture all SQL query results in SQLAlchemy without modifying the DBAPI cursor?
I'm trying to implement a system that captures all query results in SQLAlchemy for logging and analysis purposes. However, I've encountered challenges when attempting to modify the DBAPI cursor directly, as its attributes are often read-only. So it needs to:

Capture all results from SELECT SQL queries and work with different result fetching methods (fetchone, fetchmany, fetchall, iteration).
Avoid modifying the DBAPI cursor directly.
Be compatible with different database backends.

I know it's strange to expect deep copy of a cursor, but is it technically possible?
I've tried wrapping the cursor and modifying its methods, but this approach doesn't work due to read-only attributes. I'm looking for a solution that can intercept and capture query results without interfering with SQLAlchemy's internal mechanisms.
Here's a snippet of what I have attempted:
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine

def capture_query_results():
    @event.listens_for(Engine, "after_cursor_execute")
    def after_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):
        # This doesn't work due to read-only attributes
        original_fetchone = cursor.fetchone
        def capturing_fetchone():
            row = original_fetchone()
            if row:
                # Attempt to capture the row
                print(f"Captured row: {row}")
            return row
        cursor.fetchone = capturing_fetchone  # Raises AttributeError

    @event.listens_for(Engine, "after_execute")
    def after_execute(conn, clauseelement, multiparams, params, execution_options, result):
        # Attempt to capture all results
        all_results = result.fetchall()
        print(f"Captured all results: {all_results}")

capture_query_results()

This code doesn't work because we can't modify the cursor's methods, and capturing all results in after_execute might interfere with the application's normal result fetching.
